# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\xampp\htdocs\eifel\register.php on line 26

Tags: php, mysql

What's wrong with this code. I keep getting the message that is on the title above! The error is:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\xampp\htdocs\eifel\register.php on line 26

I really don't know what do do! All that is on line 26 is a curly brace!
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\xampp\htdocs\eifel\register.php on line 26

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Eiffel IM-Register</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php include "connect.php"; ?>

<?php include "functions.php"; ?>

<?php include "title_bar.php"; ?>

<div>
<h3>Register for an Eiffel Account</h3>
<p>You don't need to register if you already have a YQPCID!</p>
<form method='post'>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['register'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    if(empty($username) or empty ($password)){
            $message = "Error: Fields Empty!";
    } 
    else {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'users' VALUES('','$username','$password')");
            $message = "Successfully Registered !"
    }

    echo "<p>$message</p>";


}
?>

<form method= 'post'>
Username : <br/>
<input type='text' name='username' />
<br/><br/>
Password : <br/>
<input type='password' name='password' />
<br/><br/>
<input type='submit' name='register 'value='Register' />
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks,
User123!

Comment: Missing semi-colon. **Very** basic error.

Comment: Yep... Like John Conde already said... Add the `;` (semi colon) at the end of this statement: `$message = "Successfully Registered !";`

Comment: Use an IDE like Netbeans for example... It will show you the error. Anyways... it's really a very basic error.

Comment: okay. Thanks for the suggestion, @tastro. I'm using notepad:(

Comment: for the love of god don't use notepad - try NetBeans. You won't get downvoted on questions that are too easy that way!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a missing semi-colon.

```
$message = "Successfully Registered !"
```

should be:

```
$message = "Successfully Registered !";
```

Comment: Wow. Sorry for the late reply. Took a break from it.